# htaccess in sub-folder in code-igniter project does not work for live server but works in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website has two directory.

The root directory at www.mydomain.com and  a subfolder named "worker"
there are two htacess file in my site one is root directory:

```
wwww.www.mydomain.com:
 -htaccess
another is in 
wwww.www.mydomain.com/worker
 - htaccess
```

## Codes of root directory htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

## Codes of "worker" sub directory htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My root and "worker" folder is based on codeigniter ...
initially i had to use `"localhost/index.php/worker"` to access worker sub folder. When I used rewrite for removing `index.php` from the url, The URI rewite worked in localhost and I can see the worker folder in the localhost using `"localhost/worker"`
but on live server it gives me 404 error with the `"wwww.mydomain.com/worker"` url.

please someone solve it so that i can see the sub-folder in the live server using the url `"wwww.mydomain.com/worker"` .
Note: my hosting is based on linux and runs Apache server.

Regards
zahid

Comment: In second htaccess,last line, try to write: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] - note the '?' question mark after .php extension - saved me (and some others) few times... :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to check permission on live server it should be `755 not 777` because some times on 777 it's doesn't work..so please check the permission of htaccess file

Comment: Normally, files have 644 permissions. Do you mean the directory permissions?